# Creating a Spark Dataset in Java with a single column of increasing values

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-8, apache-spark-dataset

Newbie to Java and Spark here looking for some help:

Is there a way to create a Dataset with a single column containing increasing values from 1 to n?

```
Dataset<Row> ds = ss.createDataSet("column-name", 1, 1000);
```

Above is kind of crude in that there is no such method as `createDataSet` but I am looking for something along those lines which can lazily create contents of `ds`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using java 8 +

```
int n = 1000;
List<Integer> intList = IntStream.range(1, n+1).boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
Encoder<Integer> integerEncoder = Encoders.INT();
Dataset<Integer> primitiveDS = spark.createDataset(intList, integerEncoder);
```

Also keep in mind that When you try to create a Dataset within spark, you would need to create/pass a self generated List of Data, which is generated completely in `driver`.

Comment: If I understand it right, your solution would create `intList` with its contents in the memory and lazily create `Dataset<Integer>` later on. I am looking for a solution which does not materialize in memory the `intList` list but instead creates the `Dataset` directly.

Comment: That is fundamentally not possible in spark. Because what you are asking is the Executors to  create their own set of increasing integers.

Comment: Spark needs a reference to the complete data. Example : incase of file, it has a reference and `LOADS LAZILY` . But in your case, there is no data reference. You need to generate it. There is no concept of `lazy generation`